# How to fetch data from relationship in Core Data in iOS 8?

Tags: core-data

I have two entities Employee and Department. Both are related with Relationship i.e., 1-to-M and M-to-1. Dept is having attribute called MANAGERID representing the employee Id who is the manager of that dept.

Now i need to fetch DeptName and the Manager Name. How to write the Predicate Format String ?
NOTE: I am working in iOS 8.3 with Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the usual setup described in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), there is no need for ids. To access the department of an employee

```
let department = employee.department
```

To get all employees of a department

```
let employees = department.employees // returns NSSet or [Employee]
```

Following the design pattern of object graphs, rather than holding a manager id in the Department object, you should just have a one-to-one relationship with the manager.

```
let manager = department.manager // returns an Employee
```

This means that you need a separate relationship for the manager:

```
Department.employees <----->> Employee.department
Department.manager   <------> Employee.managedDepartment
```

*Also note that an all-caps attribute name like `MANGAERID` is illegal in Core Data.*

Comment: Hi, i used all caps just for high-lighting the attribute. As Manager is also an employee, his data is also a record in Employee entity. Any way, one Dept will have only one Manager so i have "managerId" as an attribute with in the entity "Department". While fetching "deptName" from "Department" i am also trying to fetch "employeeName" who is the manager of the dept. Hope you understand.

Comment: I am sorry for not catching you. Do you mean to say that the relationship between Dept and Employ to be reset to 1-to-1 instead of 1-to-many (or) You mean to say that i define another intermediate entity "Manager" having attributes departmentId and employeeId ? I am relatively new into iOS coding. Kindly bear with me.

Comment: No you need to have a second relationship beside the existing one. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Thanks A Lot.  I got my Data Model adjusted as per the need and data also need to be stored as per the entities and relationships so that the fetching of data from relationship is lot more convenient in swift. Thank You Once Again.

Comment: I think SQLite is managing the data more or less like an ORDBMS